# Multiple, Vertical Toolbars for mainwindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, toolbar

I want to create a mainwindow with two toolbars. First should be horizontal, on the top (classic) and the second one vertical on the right side.

I can move them once the application runs. But how can I init this setup on startup of my app?
I cannot make the second one (vertical) showing up vertically on the right side.

Current display:

[image]

Desired display:

[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QApplication, QPushButton, QTableView, QToolBar
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def jump_A(self):
        print("Hello A.")

    def jump_B(self):
        print("Hello B.")

    def jump_C(self):
        print("Hello C.")        

    def initUI(self):               

        #  textEdit = QTextEdit()
        #  self.setCentralWidget(textEdit)

        table = QTableView()
        self.setCentralWidget(table)

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('system-shutdown.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(self.close)

        AAct = QAction('A', self)
        AAct.setShortcut('A')
        AAct.setStatusTip('Jump to first entry with "A"')
        AAct.triggered.connect(self.jump_A)

        BAct = QAction('B', self)
        BAct.setShortcut('B')
        BAct.setStatusTip('Jump to first entry with "B"')
        BAct.triggered.connect(self.jump_B)

        CAct = QAction('C', self)
        CAct.setShortcut('C')
        CAct.setStatusTip('Jump to first entry with "C"')
        CAct.triggered.connect(self.jump_C)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

        toolbar_main = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        toolbar_main.addAction(exitAct)

        toolbar_speed_dial = self.addToolBar('SpeedDial')
        toolbar_speed_dial.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)

        toolbar_speed_dial.addAction(AAct)
        toolbar_speed_dial.addAction(BAct)
        toolbar_speed_dial.addAction(CAct)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main window')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMainWindow has several addToolBar() methods, in your case you are using the [`addToolBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBar-2) method that passes a string and that by default it will place it on top, if you want it to be placed on the right side you must use the method [`addToolBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addToolBar) that receives [`Qt::ToolBarArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ToolBarArea-enum) and a [`QToolBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html).

```py
# ...
toolbar_main.addAction(exitAct)

toolbar_speed_dial = QToolBar('SpeedDial')
self.addToolBar(Qt.RightToolBarArea, toolbar_speed_dial)

toolbar_speed_dial.addAction(AAct)
# ...
```

[image]